# Access server via URL or web application

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, client-server

I have a query listed below.

1) Is it possible to execute a command in server via a URL (HTML or JSP).

examples:

Find hostname URL - http ://123.456.789.1/hostname. (jsp or html)

Reply on webpage

MYHOSTNAME

So, the idea is to call the server via URL to execute predefined list of commands only and get the serveroutput on the webpage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible with jsp/java code to execute any command on server. You need to know about following in Java.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + dosCommand);
```